# Calculating P2WKH nested in P2SH addr/redeem script hash from pubkey

Tags: hash, p2sh

My calculation of the hash160 doesn't seem to be correct - what are my sins?

- Tx spending the input: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d490cc0a5b9799e09b02dd4b20a6d7ca297c09c425983efc13b382f6023d0376
- Spent output's **scriptPubKey: `OP_HASH160 032d2c15611c7b4b6941e62011e58cb5e204baa5 OP_EQUAL`**
- Spending signature:

```
'txinwitness': ['3045022100b36d2efceb87bd89466d10ee31e5c76c775d9df71095a39c38bd8c5d64fc78d202201dddf5579d993d013eb73b58110e3d280364ec47b1d7617c2f6d842e7d243d6f01',
'02d0a9b9f420d22e3c1de27e87c6ff2ec33da21302cf07688b53d72c07e88d0422']
```

- So the pubkey is `'02d0a9b9f420d22e3c1de27e87c6ff2ec33da21302cf07688b53d72c07e88d0422'`

My understanding is that the **redeem script** should be:

1. `2102d0a9b9f420d22e3c1de27e87c6ff2ec33da21302cf07688b53d72c07e88d0422ac` (classic P2SH with `OP_CHECKSIG`)
   or
2. `0002d0a9b9f420d22e3c1de27e87c6ff2ec33da21302cf07688b53d72c07e88d0422` for P2WPKH-nested-in-P2SH.  [*this is wrong, see below*]

**The expected hash output of the redeem script is:**

`032d2c15611c7b4b6941e62011e58cb5e204baa5` (see scriptPubKey above)

My hash outputs:

1. `ripe160(sha256('2102d0a9b9f420d22e3c1de27e87c6ff2ec33da21302cf07688b53d72c07e88d0422ac'))` = `9e75bbd28314946ea5bcea5e217982fce698b041`
2. `ripe160('0002d0a9b9f420d22e3c1de27e87c6ff2ec33da21302cf07688b53d72c07e88d0422')` = `1c868bec66729c87e4cb60ec6d1c8846ad86d0ee`

Saw this answer ([P2sh redeem script hash](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/p2sh-redeem-script-hash)), my calculations work fine with those inputs, but not with the above.

Related question: what is the role of the sigScript
`0014cc38458a6e5c8c09e1d8fac905fb1024c8678d88` in the input if we have the txinwitness?

***EDIT: mystery solved***

Since scriptSig was not empty, it means that the transaction was a nested P2SH transaction. In this case it is a [P2WPKH nested in BIP16 P2SH](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#p2wpkh-nested-in-bip16-p2sh).

So in order to get the expected redeem script hash `032d2c15611c7b4b6941e62011e58cb5e204baa5` (which is base58 transformed, with a 0x05 byte appended at the beginning, to obtain the bitcoin address `31yp4jocJSRG4Wa8aV7ocKSXKcdWzkHy61`):

using the scriptSig asm = `0014cc38458a6e5c8c09e1d8fac905fb1024c8678d88`

so

`ripe160(sha256('0014cc38458a6e5c8c09e1d8fac905fb1024c8678d88'))` = `032d2c15611c7b4b6941e62011e58cb5e204baa5` = desired result (which can be base58 transformed into the bitcoin address).

The scriptSig asm is in this case a P2WKH redeem script, which is obtained as from the pubkey:

`0x00 + ripe160(sha256('02d0a9b9f420d22e3c1de27e87c6ff2ec33da21302cf07688b53d72c07e88d0422'))` = `00 cc38458a6e5c8c09e1d8fac905fb1024c8678d88`